# Querying n-items based on a column

Tags: django, database, postgresql

These are my models:

```py
from django.db import models

class A(models.Model):
    # fields

class B(models.Model):
    a = models.ForeignKey(A)
    # fields
```

I have some items from `model A`:

```py
items = A.objects.filter(some_column=some_value)
```

Now I want 2 `model B` objects **for each object in** `items`. If there are 5 objects in `items` then I want total 10 objects from `model B`, 2 `model B` objects for each object of `model A`. Hope I made my requirement clear. I tried some queries, but ended up with querying `model B` for each `model A` object.

Also the solution should be **well optimized**, I would like to avoid 20 different queries for 20 objects in `items`.

If it is not possible with ORM, then I can use **raw query** as well.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can get those using related query and `prefetch_related`

like

```
items = A.objects.prefetch_related('b_set').filter(some_column=some_value)

for item in items:
    /* Here you get all modal B object for particular item */
    obj_of_modal_B = item.b_set.all() # Here b is model name in small
```

you can also overwrite related_query name using `related_name`

```
class A(models.Model):
    # fields

class B(models.Model):
    a = models.ForeignKey(A,related_name='custom_name')
    # fields
```

and then use like

```
 items = A.objects.prefetch_related('custom_name').filter(some_column=some_value)
        
 for item in items:
     /* Here you get all modal B object for particular item */
     obj_of_modal_B = item.custom_name.all()
```

Comment: thanks for the answer, I have edited my question. I should have mentioned that I want optimized solution.  I would like to avoid multiple queries on `model B` to get objects for `model A`.

Comment: edited my answer added `pefetch_related` to prevent extra database call

Comment: so this will get all the objects in `model B`, and I will have to loop through all the values and check if `a_id == A.id` ?

Comment: but only looping will done. No fetch call for model b's object to the database

Comment: though I know about this, was expecting a better solution though. Will wait for other answers. If I couldn't find a better solution, will accept yours.

Answer (score 0):

Use prefecth_related. It won't query in for loop. It will have two query only

```
a = A.objects.prefetch_related('b')
```

Read about prefetch_related in docs for more detailed information
https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.0/topics/db/queries/